# I've added a button and I want it to display a table underneath when clicked

Tags: css

I've got a bit lost with where I am with this, I've added a button and have the table done and hidden from view. All I need now is for it to display when the button is clicked. I know it's an easy one but my brain has faded.

Here's the html:

```
<div class="lotteryresults">

<button class="button button5"><b>+</b></button>
<h2>December</h2>
<p2>A responsive table will display a horizontal scroll bar   if           the       screen is too 
small to display the full content. Resize the browser window to see    the effect:</p2>

<div class="button5-content">
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
<table>

<tr>
  <td>£1000</td>
  <td>£75</td>
  <td>£50</td>
  <td>£25</td>
  <td>£10</td>
  <td>£10</td>
  <td>£10</td>
  <td>£10</td>
  <td>£10</td>
  <td>£10</td>
  <td>£10</td>
  <td>£10</td>
  <td>£10</td>
  <td>£10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>11533</td>
  <td>22978</td>
  <td>12456</td>
  <td>67849</td>
  <td>67849</td>
  <td>67849</td>
  <td>67849</td>
  <td>67849</td>
  <td>67849</td>
  <td>67849</td>
  <td>67849</td>
  <td>67849</td>
  <td>67849</td>
  <td>67849</td>
 </tr>

</table>
</div>
</div></div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
  .button {
background-color: #434343; 
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 15px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
margin: 4px 2px;
cursor: pointer;
float: right;
}
.button5 {border-radius: 80%;size: 60px;}
.button:active {
 background-color: #a1a0a0;
 box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
 transform: translateY(4px);
 }

table {
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
max-width: 1000px;margin:auto;border: 1px solid white;
}

th, td { margin:auto;
text-align: left;
padding: 6px;border: 2px solid #dadada;
}
p2 {font-family: source sans pro;padding-left:15px;padding-top: -20px;}

h2 {font-family: 
source sans pro;fontsize:45px;paddingleft:15px;color:purple;}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #b4b4b4;
margin:auto;align:center;font-family: source sans pro;}

tr:nth-child(odd){background-color: #7a7a7a;
font-family: source sans pro;font-weight:bold;}

.lotteryresults {background-color: #dadada;
width:100%;max-width:1200px;margin:auto;}

.button5-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 1000px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);}

.button5:hover .button5-content {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: You want this done with CSS? Or JavaScript?

Comment: I'd prefer CSS please as I've got no JS on the site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using

- `checkbox` and `label`
- and can position them as that `checkbox` will not be visible but only `label` is visible by using `position: absolute`.

Somthing like below

```css
.button {
  background-color: #434343; 
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}
.button5 {border-radius: 80%;size: 60px;}
.button:active {
  background-color: #a1a0a0;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;margin:auto;border: 1px solid white;
}

th, td { margin:auto;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 6px;border: 2px solid #dadada;
}
p2 {font-family: source sans pro;padding-left:15px;padding-top: -20px;}

h2 {font-family: 
  source sans pro;fontsize:45px;paddingleft:15px;color:purple;}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #b4b4b4;
  margin:auto;align:center;font-family: source sans pro;}

tr:nth-child(odd){background-color: #7a7a7a;
  font-family: source sans pro;font-weight:bold;}

.lotteryresults {background-color: #dadada;
  width:100%;max-width:1200px;margin:auto;}

.button5-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 1000px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);}

input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}

label {
  display:block;
  background: #08C;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .button5-content {
  display: block;
}


input[type=checkbox] {
 position: absolute;
 top: -9999px;
 left: -9999px;
}

label {
 display: block;
 background: #08C;
 padding: 5px;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
 border-radius: 2px;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .to-be-changed {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="lotteryresults">

  <label class="button button5" for="toggle">+</label>
  <input class="button" type="checkbox" id="toggle">

  <!-- <button class="button button5"><b>+</b></button> -->
  <h2>December</h2>
  <p2>A responsive table will display a horizontal scroll bar   if           the       screen is too 
    small to display the full content. Resize the browser window to see    the effect:</p2>

  <div class="button5-content">
    <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
      <table>

        <tr>
          <td>£1000</td>
          <td>£75</td>
          <td>£50</td>
          <td>£25</td>
          <td>£10</td>
          <td>£10</td>
          <td>£10</td>
          <td>£10</td>
          <td>£10</td>
          <td>£10</td>
          <td>£10</td>
          <td>£10</td>
          <td>£10</td>
          <td>£10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>11533</td>
          <td>22978</td>
          <td>12456</td>
          <td>67849</td>
          <td>67849</td>
          <td>67849</td>
          <td>67849</td>
          <td>67849</td>
          <td>67849</td>
          <td>67849</td>
          <td>67849</td>
          <td>67849</td>
          <td>67849</td>
          <td>67849</td>
        </tr>

      </table>
    </div>
  </div></div>
```

Hope this will help you in some way (y).

For reference check this article - http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/17/css-click-events/

Comment: The only issue with it now is the table pops up outside of the div, being as I'll be adding more than one of these tables, I'll need separater bars to clarify the results, so I'll need the tables to open up inside the div.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you started:

```
<span class="div1" tabindex="0">Hide Me</span>
<span class="div2" tabindex="0">Show Me</span>


body {
  display: block;
}
.div1:focus ~ .showMe {
  display: none;
}
.div2:focus ~ .showMe {
  display: block;
}

<p class="showMe" >Show and hide me</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, what I need is for my button to show the table below it.

Comment: @philbass44 don't you think seems this will work only if `div` is in focus and as soon as focus shifted to some other element then content will come to its natural form. - http://jsfiddle.net/6W7XD/5421/